# How do I create a custom verb for an ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

My original problem is that my `GET` request was being rejected for the parameters being too long. So I thought, oh I'll just `POST` the parameter that's getting too long.

Well that doesn't work because that parameter is `[FromUri]`. So then I thought I'll just add some verb for this specific instance, but I can't figure out how.

The question is, how would I create a verb, let's say `FOO`, that works the same as `GET`?

Comment: The Uri length restriction is not related to the verb. Can't you change the [FromUri]?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want to change it for all queries, that's why I want a new verb specifically for this case.

Comment: A POST/PUT/FOO request can have a query string as well, and this too is subject to server/client/proxy-imposed length restrictions (nowadays around 8K). Again: the Uri length restriction is not related to the verb. Why do you thing introducing a new verb will allow you to use longer query strings? The query string is part of the Uri.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm going to put the too-long contents inside $curlOptions[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]. A typical GET would ignore this, and I want it to continue to ignore it. That's why I want a new verb.

Comment: But ... CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS are going to be sent as a form (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). So you could as well just use POST? Don't confuse your fellow programmers who are going to use or work on your application, just use POST, don't invent a custom method.

Comment: @CodeCaster But the POST goes to a totally different method, which also already exists. My question is how to create a new verb. Whether it's a good idea or not is irrelevant, that's what my question is.

Comment: Wanting to create a custom verb screams [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), you're trying to solve the wrong problem in the wrong way. Is it caused by a controller that maps one verb to one action method? Can't you create a new endpoint? Anyway, see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642805/create-a-custom-http-method/36642996#36642996 for how to do so in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're entitled to your opinion but I _strongly_ disagree. I think this is the best solution to my problem without breaking existing code. A GET isn't intended to use post parameters and a POST is for creating/updating data. My options are to break the paradigm or create a new VERB for which I define the paradigm.